# Why allocation functions take std::nothrow_t by reference rather than by value?

Tags: c++

Currently, allocation functions in the standard library take `std::nothrow_t` by const reference like:

```
void* operator new  ( std::size_t count, const std::nothrow_t& tag);
void* operator new[]( std::size_t count, const std::nothrow_t& tag);
```

Since `std::nothrow_t` is simply a tag type for dispatching purposes, isn't it simpler and (possibly) more efficient to take it by value? For example:

```
void* operator new  ( std::size_t count, std::nothrow_t tag);
void* operator new[]( std::size_t count, std::nothrow_t tag);
```

What is the rationale behind the const reference design?

Comment: Probably so no copy constructor has to be called.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode I think copying of tag types is trivial and fast, and is subject to compiler optimization.

Comment: But their implementation often makes it hard for somebody to instantiate the type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the typical use of this version of `new` were to call it as `new(nothrow_t()) T`, you would have a good point. But that isn't the typical use, the typical use is `new(nothrow) T`, where `nothrow` is declared as `extern const std::nothrow_t nothrow;`. Even though there is no actual data in a `nothrow_t` type, it still takes up (at least) a byte, and in many ABIs that would mean that that (again, at least) one byte would need to be read from the `nothrow` object in order to pass it to `operator new`. Taking it by reference merely requires loading the object's address. So no, if the performance difference is measurable at all, I wouldn't expect the by-value version to be faster here.

Comment: Do you have an example of such an ABI? It seem bizarre to me to read from e.g. an empty struct S in order to copy it, just because sizeof(S) == 1. All the more if optimizations are on.

Comment: @ArneVogel Not just because `sizeof(S) == 1`, but if `S` is trivially copyable, that means copying can be done by the equivalent of `memcpy`, and an ABI could easily specify that copying *must* be done by the equivalent of `memcpy`. For a real implementation, while I don't know if its ABI really mandates this, MSVC does actually read from an empty struct if passing it by value, even if optimisations are enabled.